# HashCode isn't called by Equals explanation

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

The doc says: '`hashCode` isn't called by equals and vice-versa'.

But, reading other people comments, they actually are.

Let me put this through some easy example.
I have a `Employee` class. **`Equal method`** returns `true` if both `name` and `id` are same. While **`HashCode`** returns id.

So what happens now? I make a Set of employees and I add two employees. One has id 1 and name "a", other has id 1 and name "b". What happens? Both of them are added.

Obviously equals has been called after JAVA has seen they are in same bucket. Doesn't that violate documents from my first sentence? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I would do few things to improve your question.
When you say _The doc says.._ which document? Please list here.
Also, _But reading other people comments.._ I would add a link to a comment to another question. More importantly, I would add some code.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Stack, I wanted to make it simple so more people could read it. I am coming from myself.. I tend to skip questions with too long explanation. But thanks for tip :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are missing something:

Your statement is that the `hashCode` ***method*** does not call the `equals` method and visa versa, and generally, this is so.

This does not mean that other code that uses one of these methods doesn't call the other, and in fact often this is the case, such as a HashMap that uses the hashCode to initially assign an object to a "box" and then uses the equals method to further distinguish between different objects.   But this still does not violate my first statement.

Answer (score 1):

From Joshua Bloch's Effective Java [book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-java-3rd/9780134686097/)

> You must override hashCode() in every class that overrides equals(). Failure to do so will result in a violation of the general contract for Object.hashCode(), which will prevent your class from functioning properly in conjunction with all hash-based collections, including HashMap, HashSet, and Hashtable.

This means you need to override both `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in your `Employee` class so that when you add instances of `Employee` in a `Set` only distinct instances are added. Because **Collections** in Java such as `HashMap`, `HashTable`, `HashSet` use a corresponding `hashcode` value of an object (*instance of `Employee` in your case*) to determine how to store it inside the aforementioned collection. Later during retrieval, the `hashcode` is used in order to retrieve the unique object from the collection by using `equals()` method.

Comment: Where `hashCode()` is a function that takes an object and produces a unique numeric value.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. It makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your scenario like the code below

, First

> let's define

1. `equals()` method if two objects have the same id and the same name otherwise they are different.
2. `hashCode()` method returns the id related to the object.

> How the hash set implementations actually work?

when two objects have the same `hashCode()` this called `collision` then there is a need to check if they are equals or not.

if equals then don't add to the set because of `uniqueness`, if not equals then add.

**So short answer they are different objects and eligible to be inserted in the set**

**Hash Set implementations use HashCode to get the hash for the objects and if there is a collision then call equals to distinguish if they are same or not**

for more information about collision techniques: [Linear Probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing) [Separate chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining)

```
 static class Employee {
        String name;
        int id;

        public Employee(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Employee other = (Employee) obj;
            return id == other.id && name.equalsIgnoreCase(other.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id + " " + name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Employee> set = new HashSet<>();
        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "a");
        Employee e2 = new Employee(1, "b");
        System.out.println(e1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(e2.hashCode());
        set.add(e1);
        set.add(e2);
        System.out.println(set);
    }
```

, output

```
1
1
[1 a, 1 b]
```

Answer (score 1):

> The doc says: '`hashCode` isn't called by `equals` and vice versa'.

I am not sure which "doc" you are referring to.  (I googled for the statement that you quoted and could not find it.)  Hence it is not clear what it is actually referring to.

However, if this refers to the specific implementations of `hashCode` and `equals` in `java.lang.Object`, then it is certainly correct.

- `Object::equals(String)` simply uses `==` to compare the objects.
- `Object::hashCode()` calls `System.identityHashCode(Object)` which doesn't compare the object with anything.

> But reading other people comments, they actually are.

If you don't cite the comments, we can't explain them.

---

> Let me put this through some easy example. I have `Employee` class. The `equals(Object)` method returns `true` if both `name` and `id` are same. While `hashCode` returns the `id`.

That is a legitimate implementation, assuming that your `equals` has the right signature, and takes care of the cases where the other object `null` or where it is not an `Employee`.

> So what happens now? I make a `Set` of employees and I add two employees. One has `id` 1 and `name` "a", other has `id` 1 and `name` "b". What happens? Both of them are added.

That is correct, assuming that you are using a `HashSet`.  (`Set` is an interface.)

<sup>(It is a mistake for two `Employee` objects to have the same `id`, but that is peripheral to your question.)</sup>

> Obviously `equals` has been called after Java has seen they are in same bucket.

That is correct.

> Doesn't that violate documents from my first sentence?

No.

The statement you quoted says that `hashCode` doesn't call `equals`.  But that's not what has happened here.  What has happened here is:

1. You have called `HashSet::add(E)` to add an `Employee` to the set.
2. `HashSet::add(E)` has called `Employee::hashCode()` and used it to find the bucket<sup>1</sup>.
3. `HashSet::add(E)` has called `Employee::equals(Object)` to compare the `Employee` being added against other `Employee` objects in the bucket<sup>2</sup>.

Note that it is NOT the `hashCode` method that is calling `equals`.  So there is no contradiction.

---

<sup>1, 2 - These a drastically simplifying what happens.  Look at the source code for the full details.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To best understand the reasoning behind `equals` and `hashcode`, I would like to change your employee class a little (* see below) - let's say each Employee belongs to a Company, and each company starts their employeeNumbering from 1  (ie, each company has employeeNumber 1), so we have this :

```
public class Employee {
    int companyId;
    int employeeNumber;
    String name;
    int salary;
```

So, the companyId and employeeNumber together form the unique "primary key".  The name and salary are simply two additional fields for each Employee.

So the basic idea behind `equals` and `hashcode` are :

- `equals` uniquely identifies the object.
  For this example, therefore, `equals` would compare both companyId and employeeNumber.

  - `hashcode` identifies which "bucket" each object goes into when added to a `Set`.
    This means `hashcode` should return as wide a range of values as possible - which therefore means it should use ALL of the fields in the `equals`.

There are couple of important points to remember :

1) `hashcode` is NOT unique.  It is entirely possible and proper that the same hashcode value can be returned for two separate objects even though they are not equal (eg for this case, that they have different companyIds and/or names).

For example, a simple hashcode might be to simply add the companyId and the employeeNumber.   Yes, that is not a particularly good hashcode implementation, but it is certainly a valid one.   With that hashcode algorithm, it is easy to see that Company#1 and employeeNumer#2 would result in the same hashcode as Company#2 and employeeNumber#1.  As stated, this is NOT an error, nor even logically invalid (but it would be inefficient - as I said, it is not a good hashcode implementation).

For this reason - and I'm putting in upper case for emphasis :

`equals` SHOULD **NEVER** BE IMPLEMENTED BY CALLING `hashcode`.

2) `hashcode` should use ALL the same fields as `equals`.

The idea behind `hashcode` is that it should return as wide a range as values as possible.  This will result in objects being as widely and equally spread across the buckets in a `Set` as possible - which is good for speed.

If it does not use all the fields, then by definition the range of values returned will be less - meaning the objects will be clumped into fewer buckets, and therefore slower.

For example, if our `hashcode`  only used the companyId (and not the employeeNumber), then ALL of each company's employees would get the same hashcode.

This would be horribly inefficient.

3) `hashcode` should NEVER use fields that are not part of the `equals`

For example, if a `hashcode` used salary as well as companyId and employeeNumber, it might not be found in subsequent searches (eg if the salary has been updated - which is a perfectly permissible operation for an application to perform).

A side note is that it is common - especially in database-backed systems - for `equals` and `Dashcode` methods to solely reference the `id` field (ie the database-assigned primary key).  Be aware that this can lead to problems where `Set` operations are performed before the entities have been created (ie, the `id` is null).

ps.  (*) I changed from the Employee example in the original question, since it is not immediately evident why the `id` would not be unique - which makes using that when describing `hashcode` less clear.

Comment: Your statement in ALL-CAPS is incorrect.  For example `Integer::equals` could be implemented as a call to `Integer::hashCode`  (and an `instanceof`).  In the case of `Integer` the hashcode values ARE unique.  This is guaranteed by the specification for `Integer::hashCode`.

Comment: In fact, for any class where there is a 1-to-1 mapping between the hashCode and value, it is *possible* to use `hashCode` to implement `equals`.   Such classes are unusual, but they do exist.